# É possivel ter Java SE e Java EE na mesma máquina?

Tags: java, java-ee

Posso instalar o Java SE e o Java EE na mesma máquina?

Comment: Sim, pode. Na verdade o Java EE é o Java SE com algumas bibliotecas a mais. Já fez algo até o momento?

Comment: Removi da pergunta informações irrelevantes. Se tiver comentários, faça nos campos corretos (estes aqui, embaixo da pergunta, antes do espaço para as respostas). Seria bom esclarecer se tentou e deu algum erro/problema, ou ao menos descrever qual das duas você tem instalada já, assim as respostas e/ou comentários podem dar uma orientação mais específica caso haja algum cuidado ou observação necessários ao instalar.

Answer (score 7):

O Java EE é uma extensão para o Java SE.

Por exemplo, o Java Standard Edition inclui a API chamada JDBC para acesso ao banco de dados. O Java Enterprise Edition inclui a API chamada JPA para mapeamento objeto-relacional, que, por sua vez, usa o JDBC para acessar o banco de dados.

As APIs do Java SE, em geral, já estão disponíveis quando você instala o Java  na sua máquina. As APIs do Java EE, em geral, precisam ser incluídas à parte. Algumas APIs do Java EE são disponibilizadas pela própria Oracle, que mantém o Java, mas a maioria possui implementações alternativas que podem ser superiores em qualidade ou desempenho. Os Servidores de Aplicação como JBoss/Wildfly, Glassfish, WebSphere, Weblogic, são exemplos de servidores Java EE onde você pode instalar sua aplicação e usar  os recursos do Java EE.

Portanto, sempre que você executa algo usando Java EE, diretamente ou usando algum Servidor de Aplicação que implemente suas APIs, você já tem automaticamente o Java SE disponível.

Além disso, numa mesma máquina, você pode ter um processo do Java (JVM ou Máquina Virtual do Java) executando somente Java SE e outro processo que inclui no *classpath* as bibliotecas do Java EE.

Comment: Já tenho o Java SE instalado, posso simplesmente instalar o EE?

Comment: @user59673 Você está falando em instalar um servidor de aplicação, tal como o glassfish? Ou está confundindo JRE e JDK com JSE e JEE?